How do I use Ubuntu 'regextype egrep -regex' negative lookbehind
Assume I have the following two files:
fileA.pdf
pp_1234_fileB.pdf

If I am to run the following in PowerShell, the file, fileA.pdf is returned.
get-childitem -file -recurse | where-object {$_.Name -match "^(?!pp_[0-9]{4}_).*\.pdf"}

but if I try to do the following similar searches in WSL (Ubuntu), I do not get any files returned:
find -regextype egrep -regex '.*/(?!pp_[0-9]{4}_).*\.pdf'
find -regextype egrep -regex '.*/(?!.*pp_[0-9]{4}_).*\.pdf'

I am an extreme novice with respect to regex on Linux so I'm sure I am missing some sort of syntax mistake. Can you please point out why I'm failing and what a working solution would look like.
Thanks!

This is a lookahead, not a lookbehind.

This question is similar to: How can I use lookahead and lookbehind regular expressions on Linux using find?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Find does not support negative look behind. Instead, the following solves the above problem:
find ./ -iname "*.pdf" | grep -Po '.*/(?!.*pp_[0-9]{4}_).*\.pdf'

From what I understand (which is limited), the -P specifies to use Perl-regex and o specifies that it is only matching. With Perl, negative-lookbehind works.
